# Creation of Oracle index date column for Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

```
SELECT FILE_SUB_RET_DATE_TIME  
FROM 
    (SELECT Y.FILE_SUB_RET_DATE_TIME, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by Y.WR_FILE_TRANS_INFO_ID order by Y.FILE_SUB_RET_DATE_TIME  DESC) rowByID 
    FROM DPDBA.WORK_REQUEST_FILE_TRANS_AUDIT Y 
    WHERE Y.FILE_EVENT_TYPE = 'SUBMISSION' 
        AND Y.FILE_SUBMT_RETRL_STATUS = 'LEVEL1 POSTED' 
        AND Y.FILE_SUB_RET_DATE_TIME BETWEEN '11-DEC-2015' AND '03-FEB-2017') 
WHERE rowByID = 1;
```

I got some performance issue and we need to add the index for this date column and i am looking for help whether its going to be straight index or any thing more than that..

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you rephrase it to be more specific?

Comment: yes at current we are fetching the all the records with in the date range (FILE_SUB_RET_DATE_TIME ) and along with other columns. Now i would like to add Index for this date column. Can i use straight date index like below or i need to add some extra for this index .. CREATE INDEX IDX_WR_FILE_TRANS_AUDIT_RDT
ON WORK_REQUEST_FILE_TRANS_AUDIT (FILE_SUB_RET_DATE_TIME)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use STRINGS when you compare with DATE values, because it depends on current session NLS-Settings. Use `DATE` literal or `TO_DATE()`, functions (resp. `TIMESTAMP` and `TO_TIMESTAMP`).

It depends on your data whether Oracle will use an index on FILE_SUB_RET_DATE_TIME column, post the execution plan.

I don't think subquery is required in your case, this query should return the same result.

```
SELECT Max(FILE_SUB_RET_DATE_TIME)  
FROM DPDBA.WORK_REQUEST_FILE_TRANS_AUDIT Y 
WHERE Y.FILE_EVENT_TYPE = 'SUBMISSION' 
    AND Y.FILE_SUBMT_RETRL_STATUS = 'LEVEL1 POSTED' 
    AND Y.FILE_SUB_RET_DATE_TIME BETWEEN DATE '2015-12-11' AND DATE '2017-02-03'
GROUP BY WR_FILE_TRANS_INFO_ID;
```